# Argument-bound lifestyle in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, instance, castle-windsor

I'm letting my IoC container manage the life of my object graph and seem to be reusing a particular lifestyle a lot that is not available [in the Castle Windsor default set](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=LifeStyles&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) at the moment.

#### Example

I need to construct objects context-specifically by passing in resolution-time arguments into a factory and when I pass in the string Dorothy for instance, I would like to get back a singleton of Person that would be instantiated with string Dorothy, if it does not exist in the container yet, or otherwise the existing Dorothy instance. Same when passing the string argument Jane into my factory - please return singleton of Person Jane. And there might be Sally, Bob and many others, the complete set of inputs unravelling at runtime only.

#### Manual Implementation

Here's another example, implemented using a dictionary in my custom class:

```
private readonly static IDictionary<string,IRecruiter> Recruiters
                        = new Dictionary<string, IRecruiter>();

private IRecruiter GetRecruiter(string recruiterId)
    {
    IRecruiter recruiter;
    if (!Recruiters.TryGetValue(recruiterId, out recruiter))
                    {
                    recruiter = this.donorFactory.CreateRecruiter(recruiterId);
                    Recruiters.Add(recruiterId,recruiter);
                    }
    return recruiter;
    }
```

And where the donorFactory CreateRecruiter method does something like that:

```
return this.Create<IRecruiter>(new Arguments { { typeof(string), recruiterId }});
```

#### [SRP](http://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/archive/2009/01/26/separation-of-concern-vs-single-responsibility-principle-soc-vs-srp.aspx) and Reducing Boilerplate

I find I use this pattern a lot, so would like to know if it is somehow possible to implement using existing Castle Windsor lifestyles, or maybe there is a case made to add this pattern to Castle Windsor itself?

- Registering components as .Named does not work in this case as the set of incoming arguments is not known at design-time
- The pattern could have a general implementation that would work with any type of argument (not just string) or even sets of arguments, if GetHashCode or something like that was used as the key for the dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see one way to do it by creating a custom scope accessor:

```
public class ArgScopeAccessor : IScopeAccessor
{
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILifetimeScope> collection = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILifetimeScope>();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var scope in collection)
            scope.Value.Dispose();
        collection.Clear();
    }

    public ILifetimeScope GetScope(CreationContext context)
    {
        string name = (string)context.AdditionalArguments["name"];
        return collection.GetOrAdd(name, n => new DefaultLifetimeScope());
    }
}
```

This creates a [scope](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=LifeStyles&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Scoped_7) based on the `name` argument passed into the call to resolve the object.  I'd then use the [typed factory facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) to create an `IRecruiterFactory` (with a parameter named `name`):

```
public interface IRecruiterFactory
{
    IRecruiter Create(string name);
}
```

And assuming your `IRecruiter` and `Recruiter` are something like this:

```
public interface IRecruiter
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Recruiter : IRecruiter
{
    public Recruiter(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you could set up your container to use this scope in a reusable way like this:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

container.Register(Component.For<IRecruiterFactory>()
                            .AsFactory());
container.Register(Component.For<IRecruiter>()
                            .ImplementedBy<Recruiter>()
                            .LifestyleScoped<ArgScopeAccessor>());
```

So now, resolving a recruiter by name will resolve the same instance:

```
IRecruiterFactory recruiterFactory = container.Resolve<IRecruiterFactory>();
IRecruiter jane1 = recruiterFactory.Create("Jane");
IRecruiter susan = recruiterFactory.Create("Susan");
IRecruiter jane2 = recruiterFactory.Create("Jane");

Console.WriteLine("Jane 1: " + jane1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("Jane 2: " + jane2.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("Susan:  " + susan.GetHashCode());
```

Displays:

```
Jane 1: 60467532
Jane 2: 60467532
Susan:  63249743
```

Obviously you can create a different scope accessor to address any of the other ways you want to discriminate on types, such as hash code or a combination of arguments.  I don't, however, see a way to change the `name` constant in the `ArgScopeAccessor` since there's no way to pass a constructor argument in when configuration the scope accessor on the container.  But that could be solved with a base type and derived types just specifying the constant.

Comment: using the literal name string ["name"] will not work in production (due to obfuscation), so will try to come up with an alternative for that line, otherwise great!